# EXCEL - Shape color does not update

Tags: excel, colors, shapes

I am using the following VBA script to change the color of shape "Rectangle 56" when the color of cell "H31" is changed based on a conditional formatting.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Menu").Shapes("Rectangle 56").Fill.ForeColor.RGB =  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Menu").Range("H31").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
```

The Shape only changes color if I double click the cell "H31" and press enter. Can someone provide an idea on how to change the Shape color automatically when the cell color has changed?

Comment: Where is that line of code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.